# Passing command line options to invoked script in bash

Tags: bash, shell, command-line-arguments

Suppose I have a script `a.sh` to be invoked with options

```
a.sh -a1 a1option -a2 a2option
```

Suppose also I have a script `b.sh`, which invokes `a.sh` and uses its own options. So user executes the scripts as follows:

```
b.sh -b1 b1option -b2 b2option -a1 a1option -a2 a2option
```

Now I wonder how to parse the command line options in `b.sh`.

I do not need to parse the *entire* command line. I do not want `b.sh` to be aware of options `a1` and `a2`. I would like to get only options `b1` and `b2` and pass *the rest* to `a.sh`.

How would you do it ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As requested, this method avoids parsing the entire command line. Only the arguments up to `--` are collected for `b.sh`. Then the arguments for b are stripped and only the remaining arguments are passed to `a.sh`.

`b.sh` is invoked with `b.sh -b b1option -B b2option -- -a1 a1option -a2 a2option`. In this line, the double dash `--` indicates the end of options for `b.sh`. The following parses the options before the `--` for use by `b.sh`, then removes the b arguments from the `$@` so you can pass it to `a.sh` without worrying about what errors `a.sh` might give you.

```
while getopts ":b:B:" opt; do
    case $opt in
        b) B1=${OPTARG}
        ;;
        B) B2=${OPTARG}
        ;;
    esac 
done
## strips off the b options (which must be placed before the --)
shift $(({OPTIND}-1))
a.sh "$@"
```

A note: This method utilizes the bash builtin getopts. Getopts (as opposed to getopt, no s) takes only single-character options; hence, I have used `b` and `B` instead of `b1` and `b2`.

My favorite [getopts](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/howto/getopts_tutorial) reference.

Comment: Is the `--` delimiter is absolutely necessary ? Can I just _remove_ `b` and `B` options from anywhere in the list and pass the _rest_ of the list to `a.sh` ?

Comment: @Michael: Getopts scans $@ from left to right, so you need some way to tell getopts to stop processing options. `--`  is built in, so I used it. However, you could tell it to stop processing when it sees the first unknown option flag instead, by adding `\?) break ;;` to the list of cases, and then you wouldn't need `--`. So you want to be able to pass a list of options (with or without arguments) in no specific order? Let me see what I can come up with.

Comment: @Michael: For position independent processing use konsolebox's version, which is similar but doesn't use getopts. Modify his case `*)` to something like `ARGS_TO_KEEP+=($1);;`. Then you should get all non-b options and arguments in the array ${ARGS_TO_KEEP[@]}.

Answer (score 4):

You can do something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

while [[ $# -gt 0 ]]; do
    case "$1" in
    -b1)
        B1=true
        B1OPT=$2
        shift
        ;;
    -b2)
        B2=true
        B2OPT=$2
        shift
        ;;
    --)
        shift
        break
        ;;
    *)
        echo "Invalid option: $1"
        exit 1  ## Could be optional.
        ;;
    esac
    shift
done

bash a2.sh "$@"
```

Note that you should place your variable `$@` inside doublequotes to prevent word splitting when expanded.

Answer (score 2):

If a.sh can ignore options it doesn't know you can just call it with all the options b.sh was called:

```
a.sh "${@}"
```